# How to click the checkbox present in CheckboxWrapper class using Selenium -

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Check box present inside wrapper class

Tried with all possible methods/xpath but getting no such element exception while running script .Kindly let me know the solution

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `driver.findElement()` you can use `driver.findElements()` method.
`driver.findElements()` returns a **list** of found elements so that in case there were matches it will be non-empty list while in case of no matches it will be an empty list but in any case no exception will be thrown.